# getting related object in single row .get() query (OneToOneField )

Tags: python, django

here is my account model which is related to User

```
class Accounts(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User , unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50 , default='')
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    phone    = models.CharField(max_length=11, default='')
    mobile   = models.CharField(max_length=11, default='')
```

i want this query (ignore syntax, naming errors)

```
select accounts.* , auth_user.username , auth_user.email
from accounts 
join auth_user on auth_user.id = accounts.user_id 
where accounts.user_id = 1
```

so i can do ;

```
account = Accounts.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).select_related()
```

but since there is only 1 account with that id , i want to user .get() and show object without loop

```
account = Accounts.objects.get(user_id=user_id).select_related()
```

but i get

```
'Accounts' object has no attribute 'select_related'
```

so how do i do this join on single row selection ? basically i want to avoid using loop on object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`first`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#first) instead of get

> Returns the first object matched by the queryset, or None if there is no matching object. If the QuerySet has no ordering defined, then the queryset is automatically ordered by the primary key.

```
account = Accounts.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).select_related().first()
```

Comment: thanx that'll do  , just outta curiosity ... there is no join on .get() ?

Comment: @hretic - Because `select_related` is to be used on a queryset (since it is a database operation), where as get is returning an object

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use `get()` or `first()` - `Accounts.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).select_related().get()` will work as well. The key thing is that you call `select_related()` first.

Comment: @Alasdair - Very true, never really occurred to me to chain get on the end of a queryset. (if anyone wondering what the difference would be, get would error if there were multiple or no objects found)